# orthogonal function and inner product space

Tags: inner-products

Consider the inner product space $$\langle f,g \rangle= \int_{-1}^{1} f(x) g(x) \ dx $$

find the non zero orthogonal function with respect to $f(x)=1$ in the subspace span of ${1,e^{x}}$ ?

Comment: hi please use LaTeX as I did right now. Also please make sure the notation corresponds to your true question.

Comment: -1 to 1 is the interval. can you add it too?

Answer (score 0):

If you compute the orthogonal projektion $P(e^x)$ on span(1). Then $e^x - P(e^x)$ is in the orthogonal complement of span(1).